# Как узнать в реестре, какие файлы запускаются из Планировщика задач?

Tags: c#

Всем здравствуйте, вот имею ветку из реестра,
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule]
Вопрос, как мне вытащить из какой папки, данные о запускаемых файлах, дело в том, что в некоторых папках только такая инфа {251F4042-FAC4-46A0-9BC3-0B1821964263}.

Comment: *в некоторых папках только такая инфа {251F4042-FAC4-46A0-9BC3-0B1821964263}* Ну так дальше по цепочке парси соотв. CLSID, пока не доберёшься до нужных сведений.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо, что то подобное я предполагал, а можно как то  небольшой пример по этому вопросу.?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как узнать, какие файлы запускаются из планировщика задач?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/869452/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87)

Comment: идёшь в `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tasks\{251F4042-FAC4-46A0-9BC3-0B1821964263}` и смотришь Actions.